Windows Battery Report has no entries in the last 4 months
I have run a standard powercfg /batteryreport on my Windows 11 laptop computer.  It has entries going back to October 2020. But suddenly, in April 2024 the entries come to a conclusion, there is nothing since say April 7, 2024.  My battery currently is at 0% and cannot charge (so only runs off of wall) and I am trying to debug that.  Is it a battery needed.  Is it a charger needed.  Is it a configuration issue.  Anyone run into this, where entries simply stop at a certain date and no more entries are present?

The entries likely were wiped if you installed any significant features between 2020 and 2024, which would have been about 4, the last being 23H2.  Furthermore, if the battery is dead, you won't have any new entries since the battery is dead. Simplest solution would be to purchase a new batter as a start.

As Ramhound has said, rather than work out why your report is empty, replace the battery; it's clearly in need of replacement.

Well I did purchase a new battery and replaced it, but it is still 0% and does not say charging when the charger is connected.   So I don't know if I got a new dud battery, or something else is going on.

Please add that info to the question, and consider whether your question is about why there are no entries in that log or about how to get the battery wormy again. The questions are not the same, and one may be more helpful to you than the other.
